# sql server 2008 express - unable to connect

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I just installed sql server 2008 express on xp in vmware. My connection string looks like this

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/DEV
```

I have enabled TCP/IP

I have started Sql Server and Sql Server Browser service

I have disabled firewall.

In the same machine I installed a sql client - squirrel sql and using the above connection string, I get connection refused.

I am able to connect using SQL Server Management Studio...so I know my sql server is running.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: TYpically, SQL Server **Express** gets installed as the `.\SQLExpress` named instance - so you need to find out how to specify a **named instance** in your JDBC connection string (possibly: //localhost\SQLExpress:1433 - but that's just guessing - I don't know JDBC at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed to update TCP/IP ip addresses section.. setting the port to 1433 and restarting fixed the issue.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

I would disable named pipes. Also, try the 127.0.0.1 address. I bet the named pipes is giving you problems though.

Comment: named pipes is disabled in "Protocols for SQLEXPRESS" as well as for "SQL Native Client" Client protocols.....but no luck.....tried using 127.0.0.1 no luck either